# Polarisation of electron

Tags: electromagnetism, plasma-physics

Suppose you have a cloud of electrons each with position $\mathbf{r}_i$, basically modeling a plasma. Why can its polarisation be written as $$ \frac{-e}{V}\sum_i \mathbf{r}_i $$

Comment: Isn't polarization the dipole moment density?

Comment: If it were would that be the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *definition* of the polarization is that it is the dipole moment per unit volume, or $\vec{P}=\vec{p}/V$.  The dipole moment of an assemblage of charges is $\vec{p}=\sum_{i}q_{i}\vec{r}_{i}$.  With electrons, each of their charges is $q_{i}=-e$, which gives the formula in the question.

Note that this (a cloud of electrons) is *not* an adequate model of a plasma, since there are no positive charges present to make the overall system charge neutral.  Since the positive charges in a plasma are nuclei, which are much heavier than the electrons and thus move much more slowly, it is often reasonable to approximate the nuclei as having fixed positions (as they would have in a solid).  But the positive nuclei do need to be included to get a useful expression for $\vec{P}$.  Note that $\vec{p}=\sum_{i}q_{i}\vec{r}_{i}$ depends on the location of the origin $\vec{r}=0$ unless there the total charge $\sum_{i}q_{i}$ vanishes.

Comment: Thanks Buzz. My confusion arose from the fact that I thought the dipole moment to be $q_i \vec{d_i}$, where $\vec{d_i}$ is the vector between two charges. I never saw a definition where just the distances of the charges from the origin are computed. Isn't that the usual definition?

Comment: @Marc If you just have two (equal and opposite) charges, the dipole moment is indeed $q\vec{d}$, but that is the simplest special case of the more general formula.  The general formula gives $\vec{p}$ for *any* collection of charges.